# shaping color themes of applications

Tags: colors, theme

I am getting headaches from the light flicker (fluorescent bulbs, energy saving bulbs). The same effect has the screen raster which is a consequence of bright  dots of pixels and black lines between them.

I have just bought a new computer and it turned out I can not run old installations due to the new hardware. Being unable to change the theme is now becoming a serious problem for me. The latest OpenSuse does not even allow to set the background to black (you must use a photo) and has a number of limitations so it is completely useless for me. On Centos 7 one can only change the background. I would appreciate of the "look and feel" support back in all systems. I may not be the only one that is getting headaches.

I wonder is this a abandoned part of Gnome only so that I could use other desktops or is it just a considered an unnecessary part of system customization? Which linux releases could I use for graphics software development?

best wishes,
dusan

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the difference between desktop environment and distribution.

Distributions like Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora, Gentoo, etc. are just "sets of packages" that have a few "tweaks" to make them more desirable. Really when your talking about "Look and feel" and "distro" you generally only talkin about themes and color choices. What makes a distro good or bad has more to do with support, and update management.  What packages do they provide "special" support for and which do you have to wait for "mainstream" support for.

DE or Desktop Environments are the "desktop answer". Gnome, KDE, Unity, Cinnamon, Mate, Fluxbox, xfce, etc. etc.  There are lots of choices here, but for the most part, any distro can run any DE.

For graphics "stuff" I would recommend a lighter DE like xfce, but you will have to look at the choices and make your decision. I am trying to stay out of opinion land as much as I can.

Most importantly, without going too much into opinions, you want to look at Desktop Environments, for making things look and feel "right". And look at Distros for making thing "run smooth".